# Check website name exist or not in IIS not working

Tags: c#, iis

I created one method in c# desktop application to check web name exist in IIS or not.

But it throws the error `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Access is denied.'`.

When I open visual studio 2017 as administrator mode then it's work perfect but open it without administrator then not worked.

Below is the code :

```
public bool DoesWebsiteExist(string websiteName)
{
    bool result = false;

    DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/w3svc", "localhost"));

    foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
    {
        if (site.Properties["ServerComment"] != null)
        {
            if (site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value != null)
            {
                if (string.Compare(site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(), websiteName, false) == 0)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK using the IIS ADSI provider requires admin access, so the exception you're seeing makes sense

Comment: sorry, but didn't getting you what you want to say

Comment: The code requires admin access; why are you surprised that running it without admin access throws that exception?

Comment: Through code is it possible to give admin access or bypass this condition ?